# What do you call the grandpa's new wife after he and grandma divorce?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

After grandma and grandpa divorce, grandpa marry another person, what do you call the grandpa's new wife? Do you call her grandma?

Comment: The term step-grandparent is [widely](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0192513X19886638) [used](https://www.saga.co.uk/magazine/relationships/family/grandparenting/step-grandparents), but that doesn't really answer the question of what to call your step-grandparents. Ultimately that's a personal choice.

Comment: Call her what she asks you to call her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to several dictionaries, she would be your "step-grandmother".

stepgrandmother (plural stepgrandmothers)

> - The stepmother of one's father or mother and the wife of one's grandfather, usually a woman that one's grandfather marries after the
>   divorce of one's grandparents or the death of one's grandmother.
> - The mother of one's stepmother or stepfather.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stepgrandmother#:%7E:text=stepgrandmother%20(plural%20stepgrandmothers),of%20one%27s%20stepmother%20or%20stepfather.)]; see also

- [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/step-grandmother)
- [WordSense](https://www.wordsense.eu/stepgrandmother/)

In a more personal context, it really depends on what you want to call her by.

I don't think anyone would personally call their stepmother "stepmom" either, that sounds both awkward and derogatory.

Comment: What does 'technically' mean here, Melon D? Does it mean 'If a suitable word for this existed, it would have to be ...'? ELU doesn't run to non-standard DIY-isms. If the word exists, please give a linked, attributed supporting reference (preferably from a dictionary).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is something like an online dictionary sufficient as reference? For instance: (https://www.wordsense.eu/stepgrandmother/) Or is a more "official" source required?

Comment: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/step-grandmother) is very respectable, while [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stepgrandmother#:~:text=stepgrandmother%20(plural%20stepgrandmothers),of%20one's%20stepmother%20or%20stepfather.) is probably best here (it defines more words overall, even than OED, but has arguably less stringemt editorial policies).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for letting me know. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But if someone ask "who is your grandma?", then the answer is the grandma that divorce with the grandpa or the grandpa's new wife?

Comment: @David I think that depends on the person being asked. If that person considers their step-grandmother as close enough family, they might just answer "I have two grandmas". Similarily, if that person doesn't like her "real" grandmother, they might only mention their step-grandmother.